# durable function unable to start

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I'm having trouble to get started with azure durable functions in c#. Took this as sample and tried to start it in visual studio 2017 from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-sequence

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;

namespace VSSample
{
    public static class HelloSequence
    {
        [FunctionName("E1_HelloSequence")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> Run(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", "Tokyo"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", "Seattle"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", "London"));

            // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName("E1_SayHello")]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name)
        {
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }
    }
 }
```

But I'll get this error:
"The listener for function 'E1_SayHello' was unable to start. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: Unable to connect to the remote server. System: Unable to connect to the remote server. System: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10000."

local.settings.json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

Do i need something else to be done or should this work out of the box? What I need to have in port 10000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My spidey senses are tingling here

Did you read

[Function chaining in Durable Functions - Hello sequence sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-sequence)

**Prerequisites**

> Follow the instructions in [Install Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-install) to set up
>   the sample.

[Install the Durable Functions extension and samples (Azure Functions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-install)

**Prerequisites**

- Install the latest version of Visual Studio (version 15.3 or greater). Include the Azure development workload in your setup options.
  Start with sample functions
- Download the Sample App .zip file for Visual Studio. You don't need to add the NuGet reference because the sample project already has it.
- **Install and run Azure Storage Emulator version 5.2 or later. Alternatively, you can update the local.appsettings.json file with real Azure Storage connection strings**.
- Open the project in Visual Studio 2017. For instructions on how to run the sample, start with Function chaining - Hello sequence sample. **The sample can be run locally or published to Azure**.

The error is most likely trying to connect to the emulator and is not installed or set up.

So did you follow these steps?

[Use the Azure storage emulator for development and testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator)

Comment: Yes as you suspected. The emulator was installed but not started. Thanks for pointing that out. Now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Add  "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files"

```
"Values": {
         "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
         "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
         "AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType": "files"
 }
```